# ORA-29532: Java call terminated by uncaught Java exception: java.awt.HeadlessException

Tags: java, oracle, plsql

i execute java class to screenshot of my screen with following code:

```
import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class FullScreenCapture extends JFrame {
   private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

   public static String capture() {
      FullScreenCapture f = new FullScreenCapture();
      String Ret;
      try {
         Thread.sleep(5000);
         System.setProperty("java.awt.headless", "true");
         Robot robot = new Robot();
         String fileName = "D://FullScreenshot.jpg";

         Rectangle screenRect = new Rectangle(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit()
                                     .getScreenSize());
         GraphicsEnvironment ge = 
        GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
        System.out.println("Headless mode: " + ge.isHeadless());
         BufferedImage screenFullImage = robot.createScreenCapture(screenRect);
         ImageIO.write(screenFullImage, "jpg", new File(fileName));
         Ret ="Capture Saved Successfully";
      } catch (Exception e) {
               System.out.println("Exception occurred");
               Ret ="Wrong Error";
      }
      return Ret;
   }

}
```

the program don't have any problems when executed in netbeans or in cmd,
but when load java of java class into oracle database
to call it as function,return error message `java.awt.HeadlessException`

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using [`java.awt.Robot`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html) which needs a graphical, non-headless environment to work. As per [`Robot()` javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html#%3Cinit%3E()):

> AWTException - if the platform configuration does not allow low-level input control. This exception is always thrown when GraphicsEnvironment.isHeadless() returns true

The Oracle database server doesn't provide a graphical environment so it can't run your code. As per [User Interfaces on the Server](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/jjdev/server-user-interface.html#GUID-D74251C4-2575-411E-9361-8E333D167BA0) Oracle docs:

> Oracle Database furnishes all core Java class libraries on the server, including those associated with presentation of the user interfaces. However, it is inappropriate for code running on the server to attempt to materialize or display a user interface on the server. Users running applications in Oracle JVM environment should not be expected nor allowed to interact with or depend on the display and input hardware of the server where Oracle Database is running.

Comment: Thanks Karol for answer, i need to run this code in oracle forms when users clicked on button execute java codes as screenshot, if you have any idea please help me.